# Extracting phonemes from audio (speech) files

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, phoneme

I am looking for a toolkit/library that will allow me to extract phonemes from audio files. I see on the CMU Sphinx website that sphinx3 can be used to output phonemes, however I haven't been able to successfully build it on my windows box.

Apart from the library, what is the best way to go about building your own?

Answer (score 2):

CMUSphinx (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) is indeed the most convenient way to do that. If you have issues building it, it's probably easier to download prebuilt version or ask for help on CMUSphinx forums.

Answer (score 0):

check out allosaurus, it has a great api.

https://github.com/xinjli/allosaurus